# Making new directories with a Bourne Shell script

Tags: linux, directory

I am am new to Linux and have a question about scripts. I am interested to know how you create a new directory and copy all the files (with .txt extension) from the existing directory into it? I am familiar with the mkdir method but I am having trouble when trying to execute it within a script.

I have tried the following but there are errors. Here I am trying to copy the output to a new directory called MyTestFiles.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh

cp *.[t][x][t] > MyTestFiles
```

Comment: actuay your script does not create any drectory...

Comment: You have a directory with .txt files and you wanna copy these files to another directory?

Comment: `mkdir MyTestFiles; cp *.txt MyTestFiles`. The brackets around the letters are not needed, and the final argument to cp is the destintation for the files. See `man cp`.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback it is very helpful. @Shade - are the brackets only generally needed where you are searching for variations? e.g. searching for all files ending in .txt .TXT or .tXt you would have [tT] [xX] [tT]

Comment: @John Yes. I think you get it, but those would also match .Txt, .TXt ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "glob" (to match all files that end with ".txt", for instance):

```
mkdir MyTextFiles
cp *.txt MyTextFiles/
```

Also, if you are new to Unix/Linux, `man` is your best friend:

```
man cp
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the solution. I will make use of the manual for sure!